# Passive Voice with intransitive verbs?

Tags: passive-voice, transitive-verbs, direct-objects, intransitive-verbs

With a sentence like, "He sat on the couch," is **sat** still being used as an intransitive verb since, in general, prepositional phrases cannot act as direct objects? To me, the prepositional phase "on the couch" seems to be behaving like a direct object. If it is not behaving like a direct object, then I should not be able to construct a passive voice version of the sentence (i.e., "The couch was sat on by him"). To be sure, no one would actually use this passive voice construction, but it was nonetheless possible to create.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The passive voice is of course "_The couch was sat on by me_", though it sounds unnatural. And the verb _sat_ as used in your sentence is of course intransitive.

Comment: In other words, we can form a 'prepositional passive', "The couch was sat on" (using a short passive for greater naturalness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, "on the couch" is actually functioning as an adverbial phrase modifying "sat". It answers the question "where?"

If it were functioning as a direct object, your passive construction would be something like, "On the couch was sat by me," which is nonsensical. As it is, in the passive voice, the word "on" is in proximity to the verb it modifies, "sat".

Comment: Yes, the preposition _on_ is being treated as a transitivizer, like _into_ in _That matter has been looked into_. In effect, _sit on_ is being treated like a transitive verb. Happens all the time; just an alternative parse.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you have a particular book you'd recommend for learning to parse sentences?

Comment: @Eric1982 If you have a lot of time, I'd recommend [McCawley 1998](https://www.google.com/search?q=mccawley+1998). It's not an ESL text, though; it's intended to teach English syntax to native speakers. But it has all the information. It's just that it's a textbook for a 1-year college course in advanced English syntax, and while it's very clear and concise, it leaves in all the details and it's very very complicated. I'd compare it to a year's college course in vector analysis for difficulty.

Comment: And that is why I feel intimidated every time I begin to answer a question and think, What would @JohnLawler say about this?

Comment: @RobJarvis What? You didn't like vector calculus? How about a year's course in mammalian evolution, with lab?

Comment: "Sat" can be transitive, e.g. "I sat my baby on the floor," or "They sat the pot plant in the centre of the room." This use is infrequent.

Comment: @PaddyLandau, the word you are looking for is "set" not "sat". **Set** is transitive. **Sat** is intransitive. Always.

Comment: And @JohnLawler, I studiously avoided those classes in college. :-)

Comment: _Set_ is the official causative for intransitive _sit_; but _sit_ is often used causatively without benefit of vowel change, especially in phrasal verbs.

Comment: @RobJarvis — Thank you for the correction. In England, many people use "sat" incorrectly, as, "I was sat on the bench" instead of "I was sitting on the bench." They do the same with "stood" instead of "standing."